# How to plot sliding average in ltspice?

Tags: ltspice

I would like to plot a sliding average of some voltages and currents. Ideally I would just add a new trace with some expression, but all expressions that I found so far only operate on single values.

Are there any expressions (like absdelay for B sources) that would do the trick?

Comment: In microcap, the transient analysis machine allows you to display (say) "v(V1)" and "avg(v(V1))" - look for something like this.

Comment: @Andyaka: I don't think that I want to spend that much for a hobby.

Comment: Dude I said - "look for something LIKE this"

Comment: @PlasmaHH curious how you implement a sliding average in a B source with absdelay ?

Answer (score 10):

**Summary**
To plot the the moving (sliding) average use **.MEAS,.PARAM and .STEP** LTSpice directives (see the detailed explanation below). As a quick *partial* solution, use **zoom in and Ctrl+Click** on a plot title to show the average value (only a single value, not plot) for the selected abscissa range.

**Solution. Plotting moving average for a signal**

Suppose there is a following set-up and one needs to know the moving average of V(out):

[image]

*Step 1: create the directive*

Create the following SPICE directive (Edit -> Spice Directive):

```
.param t=0
.step param t 100n 900n 100n
.param S=100n
.meas tran Moving_Average avg(v(out)) TRIG time VAL=n-S/2 TARG time VAL=n+S/2
```

Comment for the directive:

*1st line:* define a time variable t.
*2nd line:* Step t from 100ns to 900 ns with the step 100ns.
*3rd line:* Set the moving average span: 100 ns.
*4th line:*  Syntax: 
Moving_Average - the name of the newly created variable to be calculated (put here whatever you like).
TRIG time VAL=t-S/2 - start of averaging.
TARG time VAL=t+S/2 - end of averaging.
E.g. if t=300 ns, averaging spans from 250 ns till 350 ns (300 +/- 100/2).

*Step 2: run simulation, open the log file and plot the moving average*

Run simulation

[image]

Open the Spice Error Log (View -> Spice Error Log), right click on any place and select Plot Stepped Measured Data

[image]

See the moving average plotted

[image]

**Quick *partial* solution (see average value for a specified time range)**

Suppose one has a chart like this:

[image]

And wishes to calculate an average value during [0.7us,0.8us].

*Step 1: Specify the time range.*

Double click on the abscissa axis and specify the needed range. Alternatively use Zoom to Rectangle tool (magnifier button in the top bar).

[image]

*Step 2: Calculate the average*

Ctrl + left mouse click on a chart title (bold green title V(out) in the picture) to see the average value *for the specified range*.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most variants of spice will allow you to print a trace to a file (choose text mode to make it more portable) which you can manipulate in a spreadsheet or your own code.  That is how I do it in HSPICE, TSPICE etc.. The way that SPICE operates is that it computes ahead, determines if the results are within bounds and if not, it stops, re-evaluates the bias points changes time step and recomputes, so it jumps back and forth in a jittery fashion and then streams to the output.

Answer (score 3):

There is another method, besides Sergei Gorbikov's methods. `.MEAS`, `.STEP`, or `Ctrl+Click`, though very viable, imply running the simulation and then seeing the results. If you need a quasi-real-time plot, you can use definite integration, which is nothing but a moving-average in an analog way: [How to integrate a signal in LTSpice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254602/how-to-integrate-a-signal-in-ltspice/254603#254772) (link only, rather than repeating the answer). The results would be plotted as the simulation goes, with a period delay. A better solution would be integrating first and then delaying, in which case the integrators can be `G+C`, which are a much better choice than `idt()`.

If you know your signal to be periodic with no even harmonics, you could modify the circuit to be only half a period delay, by adding a home-brew quadrature to the input (simple pi/2 delay, derived from the original input). If your frequency has a variable period, you could use the behavioural source version of the definite integration, where `delay()` could have passed an external, variable delay. This delay could be an lowpass filtered version of the pulsed output, properly scaled.

If absolute real-time is needed, I'm afraid that's simply not possible, unless your modulation (error) voltage and the carrier are known, but then you could simply plot `V(err)` as a function of the carrier's amplitude.